# EntityFramework-Plus check if data implements an interface

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-plus

I have a filter

```
 this.Filter<BaseModel>(q => q.Where(x => x.CompanyId == companyId);
```

Is there a way to check whatever "x" is implementing my custom interface "IGlobalDatabaseObject" ?

```
 this.Filter<BaseModel>(q => q.Where(x => x.CompanyId == companyId || x is IGlobalDatabaseObject ); ?
```

So, the db queries will return the data where "x.CompanyId== companyId" or if that data implements Global Interface

I am using Ef plus library (github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus )

Comment: Not sure this will work well with Entity Framework. Are you checking if `BaseModel` implements `IGlobalDatabaseObject` or is there some inheritance going on here?

Comment: I am using a EF Plus library. https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/ . The inheritance is :  Model:BaseModel,IGlobalDatabaseObject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are seeking for 
[EF+ Query Filter Enable/Disable](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/wiki/EF-Query-Filter-%7C-Entity-Framework-Dynamic-Instance-and-Global-Filters#ef-query-filter-enabledisable) feature. In your case, something like this:

```
// The key identifying your filter
var key = new object();

// Create filter for classes that inherit BaseModel
this.Filter<BaseModel>(key, q => q.Where(x => x.CompanyId == companyId));

// Disable the filter for classes that implement IGlobalDatabaseObject
this.Filter<IGlobalDatabaseObject>(key).Disable();
```